# Use of undeclared type MGSwipeTableCell

Tags: ios, swift3, frameworks

I'm pretty new to swift and I have an error.
I'm trying to use pod MGSwipeTableCell https://github.com/MortimerGoro/MGSwipeTableCell
Installed pod 'MGSwipeTableCell' in pod file. Got it in pods in file inspector.

var cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(reuseIdentifier) as! MGSwipeTableCell!

throws me an error Use of undeclared type 'MGSwipeTableCell'
There is a project on google disk https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By_KH6PH75z2OHlXek85YmRpcGc/view
It should be something simple I missed. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add import statement in the beginning of file where you use it

```
import MGSwipeTableCell
```